# How to open jetpack DataStore file (.preferences_pb)

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

I am trying out new jetpack [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) library . I saved data using the library . This created a file `settings.preferences_pb`  in app data directory (/data/data/my.package.name/files/datastore/settings.preferences_pb) . `setting` is the file name given by me .  The data doesn't show properly with a text viewer .  I can make out Key name but the value is garbage . How do I open this file and view it ?

Here is the drive link for file [settings.preferences_pb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXLbmxaAs5__MkbBFYrvRLQucgRFFOl4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Currently there doesn't seems to be option to view such data. It will be needing parser to understand how its internally stored. Android Studio 4.1 is going to come with Database Inspector(after this many years :P) but don't think there will be any for Datastore through IDE. Only options currently is to retrieve programmatically & check OR write test case to check the basics.

Comment: Any update on this? Like what exactly is this file format - .preferences_pb? Is this like a variation of the .pb format? And how to open this?

Comment: @KashishMalhotra no did get any info ,

Comment: @Manohar Please check my answer on the same.

Answer (score 11):

Reference: https://medium.com/swlh/get-your-hand-dirty-with-jetpack-datastore-b1f1dfb0a5c1

---

The protobuf files will be located in /data/data/{application.package}/files/datastore/ . These are the protobuf formatted files, so we can not read them with an ordinary editor. To decode the files, we can use [protoc](http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html) command line.

> To be able to use protoc command, we have to pull these files to our
> workstation’s space using adb command

For preference datastore

```
protoc --decode_raw < app_name.preferences_pb
```

The result will be similar to this:

```
1 {
    1: "app_name"
    2 {
        5: "Datastore sample"
    }
}
1 {
    1: "is_demo_mode"
    2 {
        1: 1
    }
}
```

Note: value 1 of is_demo_mode represents a true

Answer (score 3):

Here is the current format for the preferences_pb file: [link](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:datastore/datastore-preferences-core/datastore-preferences-proto/src/main/proto/preferences.proto;drc=92611da8326775f64811228fb98297f6b7cf725a)

You can parse the file using this schema and print it out if you need to.

Alternatively, you can just use the toString() method on the Preferences object and you should get a nice readable output.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Reading preferences_pd file]
I used an Hex Editor ("Hex Fiend" for macOS) and it seems understandable.

You may refer to the [preferences.proto](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:datastore/datastore-preferences-core/datastore-preferences-proto/src/main/proto/preferences.proto;drc=92611da8326775f64811228fb98297f6b7cf725a) here (thanks @rohit-sathyanarayana)

The binary file is a map of <string, value> pair.

Each pair starts with `0x0A` and length (in bytes). For example `0x26` means next 38 bytes.

Name field starts with `0x0A` and length (in bytes). For example `0x04` for "name" and `0x05` for "token".

Value field starts with `0x12` and length (in bytes). For example `0x1E` = next 30 bytes.

First byte might indicates field type.  For example `0x2A` = String field.

Second byte is length of value.  For example `0x1C` = 28 bytes.

Since `0x0A` is same as line feed, you can open the preferences_db as text if most of your fields are in String format.

Answer (score 0):

[image: code]

I find a workaround from the datastore source code. Just change the pbFile to File(filesDir, "datastore/settings.preferences_pb")